# Invalid version or the data in not in 'javabin' format

Tags: java, apache, solr

I am currently integrating from solr 1.4 to solr 3.4. After executing the codes, I got the following error message.

```
15:56:09,575 ERROR [STDERR] [SolrServerException] QueryResponse SOLRSearchWorker. generateResponse(SolrQuery, SolrServer, SolrRequest.METHOD) message: 
15:56:13,150 ERROR [STDERR] org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version or the data in not in 'javabin' format
15:56:13,152 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrServer.request(LBHttpSolrServer.java:217)
15:56:13,152 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:89)
15:56:13,153 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:122)
15:56:13,153 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.cambridge.ebooks.production.solr.util.SOLRSearchWorker.generateResponse(SOLRSearchWorker.java:153)
15:56:13,154 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.cambridge.ebooks.production.solr.util.SOLRSearchWorker.searchCore(SOLRSearchWorker.java:58)
15:56:13,155 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.cambridge.ebooks.production.solr.util.EBookSearchWorker.searchBookCore(EBookSearchWorker.java:161)
15:56:13,155 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.cambridge.ebooks.production.ebook.EBookWorker.getQuickSearchResult(EBookWorker.java:113)
15:56:13,156 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.cambridge.ebooks.production.ebook.EBookManagedBean.doSearch(EBookManagedBean.java:248)
15:56:13,156 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.cambridge.ebooks.production.ebook.EBookManagedBean.getInitBooks(EBookManagedBean.java:163)
15:56:13,157 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:56:13,157 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
15:56:13,158 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
15:56:13,158 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
15:56:13,159 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
15:56:13,159 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:53)
15:56:13,160 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:71)
15:56:13,160 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:118)
15:56:13,161 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
15:56:13,161 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:101)
15:56:13,162 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
15:56:13,162 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
15:56:13,163 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:164)
15:56:13,163 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:201)
15:56:13,164 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:351)
15:56:13,164 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:160)
15:56:13,165 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
15:56:13,165 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
15:56:13,166 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
15:56:13,166 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
15:56:13,167 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1643)
15:56:13,168 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
15:56:13,168 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.doRenderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:427)
15:56:13,169 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:229)
15:56:13,169 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
15:56:13,170 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:269)
15:56:13,171 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
15:56:13,171 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
15:56:13,172 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
15:56:13,172 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
15:56:13,173 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
15:56:13,173 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
15:56:13,174 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
15:56:13,174 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.cambridge.ebooks.production.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:62)
15:56:13,175 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
15:56:13,175 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
15:56:13,176 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.cambridge.ebooks.production.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:69)
15:56:13,177 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
15:56:13,177 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
15:56:13,178 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
15:56:13,178 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
15:56:13,179 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
15:56:13,180 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
15:56:13,180 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
15:56:13,181 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
15:56:13,181 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
15:56:13,182 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
15:56:13,183 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
15:56:13,183 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
15:56:13,184 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
15:56:13,184 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
15:56:13,185 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
15:56:13,185 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
15:56:13,186 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
15:56:13,186 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
15:56:13,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
15:56:13,188 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
15:56:13,189 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version or the data in not in 'javabin' format
15:56:13,189 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:99)
15:56:13,190 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BinaryResponseParser.processResponse(BinaryResponseParser.java:39)
15:56:13,190 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:466)
15:56:13,191 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:243)
15:56:13,191 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrServer.request(LBHttpSolrServer.java:205)
15:56:13,192 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 65 more
```

Then, I tried to debug and found out that the Query response is returning null because of this java bin format. I need help to fix this code, I tried all the possible solution I found in internet, but no luck. Anyone can help?? this is for my major release of project in my company.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this may be an issue with different versions between client and server.

Comment: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SolrJ-new-javabin-format-td1715912.html

Comment: Hi James, 
I am using the same version of solr-core and solrJ.both 3.4.0

Comment: I would double check you do not have a solr-related jar in your classpath for the client which is not at version 3.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually related to either a version difference in Java itself between the server and the client, but more often it's caused by the server throwing an error and the application container returning an error page instead of the expected javabin formatted response.

Check the server log to see if it's not throwing an exception, and then attempt the same request in your browser (the server should have a log of the query and the parameters included) to see what the server actually responds with.